# TCA9548a (I2C multiplexer) C++ integration

Tags: c++, arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c, sensors

I have 4 VL680 laser distance sensors to use with à Raspberry. It is a I2C bus compatible sensor but we can't change the address. So, I use the TCA9548a Adafruit board I2C multiplexer. I can run only one VL680 directly on my I2C bus but it won't work trough the multiplexer. Datasheet is not clear and I find only code for Arduino or bad Python example.

Here I am :

```
char filename[20];
const int adapter_nr = 1;
snprintf(filename, 19, "/dev/i2c-%d", adapter_nr);
file = open(filename, O_RDWR);
if (file < 0) 
{
    printf("Unable to connect reach I2C bus \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// multiplex address
const int addr = 0x70;

if(ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0) 
{
    printf("Fail to reach multiplex laser \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

char buf[10];
buf[0] = 0x01; // to select channel 0
write(file, buf, 1);
I2C_init();

doTheSameAsOneOnlyVL680();
...
```

I don't know how I must do and nothing help. Is that the way to select the channel ? How write and read then ?

```
void I2C_init()
{   
    const int addr = 0x29;

    if(ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0) 
    {
        printf("Fail to reach laser \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(read_byte(file, 0x000) != 0xB4)
    {
        printf("Problem with VL6180X\n");
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int setup = read_byte(file, 0x016);

    if(setup == 1)
    {
        printf("Init all registers \n");
        write_byte(file, 0x0207, 0x01);
                ...

    }
    else
    {
        printf("Fail \n");
    }

    set_scaling(file, 1);
}
```

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but the size you pass to the [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) function is *including* the terminator. Therefore you can pass e.g. `sizeof filename` instead of using a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Also, if you program in C++, why don't you use `std::string`?

Answer (score 1):

When  `ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr)` runs you're saying **"On I2C talk to the multiplexer."**

Then, with

`buf[0] = 0x01; // to select channel 0
write(file, buf, 10);`

you make the multiplexer connect the VL680 that's connected to multiplexer first port to the I2C bus.

After you talked to the multiplexer with

`write(file, buf, 10);`

and before you talk to the distance sensor with

`doTheSameAsOneOnlyVL680();`

you need to run some code in order to say **"On I2C talk to the distance sensor."**

Something like:

```
if(ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, vl680Addr) < 0) 
{
    printf("Fail to reach distance sensor \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

, where `vl680Addr` is the address (you'll need to define that) for the VL680 laser distance sensor,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thing we are in the right direction. I am able to connect to the sensors because ioctl is showing no error. But I can't read/write to sensor regs. Here is the initialize code of each sensor (first step of doTheSameAsOneOnlyVL680). I have edited my question.

Comment: I change in my I2C_init() function file to file2 for the test and there it says unable to reach laser... I am bad with my channel select.

Comment: I'm not clear..., without the multiplexer, are you able to write/read to/from one sensor? If not, I think you'll need to get that working before connecting more sensors.

Comment: Yes. I can easily.

Comment: Maybe try I2C_SLAVE_FORCE instead of I2C_SLAVE